# IntentService is not being called

Tags: android, service, intentfilter, intentservice

I am trying to send an Intent from the onCreate in an Activity to start an IntentService.  However the IntentService's onHandleIntent is never being received.  I have tried changing around the Manifest with Intent-filters but nothing seems to be working.  No exceptions are being thrown, but the IntentService is simply not called.

Here is the onCreate

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    db = new TwitterDB(this);
    String[] columns = new String[1];
    columns[0] = TwitterDB.TEXT;
    tAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 0, null, columns, null, 0); 
    tweets = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listtwitter);
    tweets.setAdapter(tAdapter);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SyncService.class);
    intent.putExtra("action", SyncService.TWITTER_SYNC);
    this.startService(intent);

}
```

Here is the creator and onHandleIntent of the IntentService class, I know it is not being called because logcat never shows "Retrieved intent".  The constructor is not called either (There was a log call in there, but I removed it.

```
public SyncService(){
    super("SyncService");
    twitterURI = Uri.parse(TWITTER_URI);
    Log.i("SyncService", "Constructed");
}

@Override
public void onHandleIntent(Intent i){
    int action = i.getIntExtra("action", -1);
    Log.i("SyncService", "Retrieved intent");
    switch (action){
        case TWITTER_SYNC:
            try{
                url = new URL(twitterString);
                conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                syncTwitterDB();
                conn.disconnect();
            }catch(MalformedURLException e){
                Log.w("SyncService", "Twitter URL is no longer valid.");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }catch(IOException e){
                Log.w("SyncService", "Twitter connection could not be established.");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
        default:;
            // invalid request
    }
}
```

And here is the Manifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.twitter"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"               
         android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".TwitterTwoActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        <service android:name="SyncService"/>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Move your service declaration outside of the scope of the TwitterTwoActivity in the XML file, as I have done here:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.twitter"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"               
         android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".TwitterTwoActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>  
    <service android:name="SyncService"/>

</application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 9):

You need to define the path to the service in your manifest, simply putting the name is not sufficient.

Change

```
<service android:name="SyncService"/>
```

to

```
<service android:name=".SyncService"/>
```

if SyncService is in the root of your package, add respective folder before `.SyncService` if needed.

Comment: Thanks, that is proper practice, but it is in the correct folder, I think